# Symfony 3 doctrine show content from relationship on repo

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have two Symfony entities `SrvrsServers` and  `NcBackupEvents`:

- NCbrtBundle:SrvrsServers (id, name, description, etc)

Relationship code:

```
 /**
 * One SrvrsServers has Many NcBackupEvents.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NcBackupEvents", mappedBy="SrvrsServers")
 */
private $ncBackupEvents;

public function __construct() {
    $this->ncBackupEvents = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

- NCbrtBundle:NcBackupEvents (id, date, status, etc)

This is on `NcBackupEvents`:

```
 /**
 * @var \SrvrsServers
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SrvrsServers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="srvrs_servers_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $srvrsServers;
```

The relationship is OneToMany from `SrvrsServers` to `NcBackupEvents`. On the repo of `NcBackupEvents` i'm able to pull information about itself. This works and I think the `SrvrsServers` object gets pulled, but I am not 100% sure and also do not know how to access it:

```
class NcBackupEventsRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findByServerBackup($parameters)
    {
        $dql = 'SELECT n FROM NCbrtBundle:NcBackupEvents n 
            WHERE n.backupmethod LIKE :backupmethod
            AND n.backupType LIKE :backup_type 
            AND n.log LIKE :log';
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery($dql)
                ->setParameter('backupmethod',
                    '%'.$parameters['backupmethod'].'%')
                ->setParameter('backup_type',
                    '%'.$parameters['backup_type'].'%')
                ->setParameter('log', '%'.$parameters['log'].'%');
       try {
            return $query->getResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return null;
       }
    }
}
```

How can I QUERY from Controller using the `SrvrsServers->name` field for instance? I have tried many things and nothing seems to work. This should be very simple, but I do not understand how to get it done. I have tried to follow the [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#joining-related-records) and can not get it to work for some reason. Can someone point me the way to do this? Please keep present that I am a newbie.

EDIT: SAMPLE Controller.

```
 /**
 * @Route("/")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $paramaters = array('backupmethod' => 't-py',
        'backup_type' => '', 'log' => 'fuc');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('NCbrtBundle:NcBackupEvents')
            ->findByServerBackup($paramaters);
    foreach($em as $value){
        print_r(gettype($value));
        print_r($value->getSrvrsServers()->getName());
    }
    return $this->render('NCbrtBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

EDIT2: I want to include the server `name` on the `$paramaters` variable from the `SrvrsServers` entity

Comment: Can you add the controller to the post because you can t get a parameter in Repository

Comment: show the call to your `findByServerBackup` on your controller

Comment: Added the controller, but I did not add the reference... is just a sample controllet to get let say the `SrvrsServers` name... nothing else for now What I NEED is to be able to query by let say `SrvrsServers->name`

Comment: @Abel rename your classes/bundles, it's not readable `SrvrsServers` and `NCbrtBundle:NcBackupEvents`.

Comment: @PeterPopelyskho I can't do that for historical reasons. Not my DB. I am just developing a small part of it. This is just not under my control.